# Doctrine ORM and slim php - Adding a class manually for an newly created table

Tags: doctrine, slim

I'm working on a legacy app, and this is my first time using doctrine (normally a rails guy).

I manually created a new table on the db called "SNACKS" (naming convention was all caps).

I created a models/entities/Snack.dcm.yaml file:

```
Snack:
    type: entity
    table: SNACKS
    fields:
        id:
            id: true
            type: integer
            unsigned: false
            nullable: false
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
        patient_id:
            type: integer
            unsigned: false
            nullable: false
        snack_name:
            type: string
            length: 50
            fixed: false
            nullable: false
        created_at:
            type: datetime
            nullable: false
        updated_at:
            type: datetime
            nullable: false
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

But still get this error: `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 14 near 'Snack s': Error: Class 'Snack' is not defined.`

I also noticed there were some files in the model dir "model/" and copied that over as well:

```
<?php



use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Snacks
 */
class Snack
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $patient_id;

    /**
     * @var text
     */
    private $snack_name;

    /**
     * @var datetime
     */
    private $created_at;

    /**
     * @var datetime
     */
    private $updated_at;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getPatientId()
    {
        return $this->patient_id;
    }


    public function setPatientId($patient_id)
    {
            $this->patient_id = $patient_id;
        return $this->patient_id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Medicines
     */
    public function setSnackName($name)
    {
        $this->snack_name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSnackName()
    {
        return $this->snack_name;
    }

    /**
     * Set generic
     *
     * @param string $generic
     * @return Medicines
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($datetime)
    {
        $this->created_at = $datetime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get generic
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->created_at;
    }

    /**
     * Set contraInd
     *
     * @param string $contraInd
     * @return Medicines
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt($datetime)
    {
        $this->updated_at = $datetime;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

- note the comments are wrong in that because I copied it from an existing file and changed what I needed.

Any ideas why Doctrine is not finding the class?

Answer (score 0):

Well, figured it out the by going through a doctrine tutorial and ending up on the bootstrap.php file for composer.

It looks like the previous developer manually required all the model files, so I had to add the require there.

Hope that helps someone.